# Google Analytics - get iOS in app purchase values

Tags: ios, objective-c, transactions, google-analytics, in-app-purchase

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial) to successfully implement in app purchasing in my iOS app.

I'm now trying to implement Google Analytics to track purchases with the following code.  But on successful purchase completion I'm unsure where to get the actual values from.

Any sample code would be greatly appreciated.

```
- (void)onPurchaseCompleted {
  GAITransaction *transaction =
      [GAITransaction transactionWithId:@"0_123456"            // (NSString) Transaction ID, should be unique.
                        withAffiliation:@"In-App Store"];      // (NSString) Affiliation
  transaction.taxMicros = (int64_t)(0.17 * 1000000);           // (int64_t) Total tax (in micros)
  transaction.shippingMicros = (int64_t)(0);                   // (int64_t) Total shipping (in micros)
  transaction.revenueMicros = (int64_t)(2.16 * 1000000);       // (int64_t) Total revenue (in micros)

  [transaction addItemWithSKU:@"L_789"                         // (NSString) Product SKU
                         name:@"Level Pack: Space"             // (NSString) Product name
                     category:@"Game expansions"               // (NSString) Product category
                  priceMicros:(int64_t)(1.99 * 1000000)        // (int64_t)  Product price (in micros)
                     quantity:1];                              // (NSInteger)  Product quantity

  [[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker sendTransaction:transaction]; // Send the transaction.
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my final code:

```
- (void)trackPurchaseWithTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction andAction:(NSString *)action
{
    //Only track purchase, not restore
    if(![action isEqualToString:IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification]) return;

    id tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];

    SKPayment *payment = transaction.payment;
    NSString *sku = payment.productIdentifier;
    SKProduct *product;

    for(SKProduct *skProduct in skProducts) {
        if([skProduct.productIdentifier isEqualToString:skProduct.productIdentifier]) {
            product = skProduct;
        }
    }

    NSLocale *priceLocale = product.priceLocale;
    NSString *currencyCode = [priceLocale objectForKey:NSLocaleCurrencyCode];
    NSString *transactionId = transaction.transactionIdentifier;
    NSNumber *productPrice = product.price;
    NSNumber *revenue = @(productPrice.floatValue * payment.quantity);

    GAIDictionaryBuilder *transBuilder = [GAIDictionaryBuilder createTransactionWithId:transactionId
                                                                      affiliation:@"App Store"
                                                                          revenue:revenue
                                                                              tax:0
                                                                         shipping:0
                                                                     currencyCode:currencyCode];
    [tracker send:[transBuilder build]];

    GAIDictionaryBuilder *itemBuilder = [GAIDictionaryBuilder createItemWithTransactionId:transactionId
                                                                                 name:product.localizedTitle
                                                                                  sku:sku
                                                                             category:@"In-App Purchase"
                                                                                price:productPrice
                                                                             quantity:@(payment.quantity)
                                                                         currencyCode:currencyCode];
    [tracker send:[itemBuilder build]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how to get price for a product and show it to the user, this is how you do it. This is all take from this [Tutorial](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/)

```
- (void)requestProUpgradeProductData
{
    NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:... ];//create your set
    productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
    productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [productsRequest start];
}

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    NSArray *products = response.products;
    proUpgradeProduct = [products count] == 1 ? [products firstObject] : nil;
    if (proUpgradeProduct)
    {
        NSLog(@"Product title: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.localizedTitle);
        NSLog(@"Product description: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.localizedDescription);
        NSLog(@"Product price: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.price);
        NSLog(@"Product id: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.productIdentifier);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. actually it was more related to Google Analytics